# How to see what a .exe application is doing in cmd?

Tags: process, cmd, admin, explorer

I have an .exe application that when clicked open cmd and instantly closes cmd, what im assuming is it opens cmd, types in a command that does something (in my case it opens an application that usually requires the admin password without you needing to type it in, makes it easier for the kids to open things like sony vegas) but I want to make sure that all the exe file is doing is opening the app.

since it opens cmd and instantly closes it i'll take a gander and say its opening cmd and typing in commands that start the application (there is a specific exe file for each application I open)

I want to see what the .exe is typing into cmd, or I want to see were the resource (if available) files are for the exe, or I want to see the application log for the exe to know what its doing.

i tried using process explorer but because the application opens and then instantly closes there isn't much info on it, and i don't know were to look in PE to find out what i need to know.

Comment: Why don't you run a CMD terminal window and then go to the path of the exe you want to run and execute it from command prompt? If the exe is printing something, you can see that on the terminal

Comment: I opened cmd and typed start (then the file directory of the .exe) all it did was open a new cmd which instantly closed

Comment: OK. Dont type start, just the complete path of exe .